# Force Android SDK LocationManager to provide the current location

Tags: android, gps

I'm having problems with the LocationManager not providing a last known location and not updating the location.
The code has worked and still works under certain conditions. In short I do the following and yes, I have all the permissions set up and GPS and WLAN are activated.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } catch(SecurityException e ) {
        Log.d("GPS", "Security Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } catch(SecurityException e ) {
        Log.d("GPS", "Security Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } catch(SecurityException e ) {
        Log.d("GPS", "Security Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

The `locationListener` is a simple implementation of the `LocationListener` interface and just stores the provided location from `onLocationChanged(Location location)` and prints it out via `Log.d("GPS", location.getProvider()+" "+location.toString());`for debugging purposes.

If the phone does not use GPS for quite a while (I haven't found out how much time exactly has to pass) it will not provide a location via `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` (it will return `null` and it will not call my `locationListener`. I've waited about 30 minutes but nothing has been updated.

On the other hand, when I open Google Maps (e.g. in browser) I will get an immediate location and when I open my app now I will also get a location update.

So how do other apps force Android to provide a new location?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "If the phone does not use GPS for quite a while" -- what do you mean by this, with respect to your code? Are you saying that you request updates, get a location, remove updates, let the device sit for a while, then request updates again, and you do not get a location?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Also no google maps, no nothing. The phone just sits there not being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose best provider via criteria. instead of if condition use below code. see more details https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/android-gps-positioning-location-strategies/

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), 0, 0, locationListener);


String getProviderName() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); // Chose your desired power consumption level.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true); // Chose if speed for first location fix is required.
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); // Choose if you use altitude.
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false); // Choose if you use bearing.
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false); // Choose if this provider can waste money :-)

    // Provide your criteria and flag enabledOnly that tells
    // LocationManager only to return active providers.
    return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
}
```

Comment: also use location location listener instead of calling locationManager.getLastKnownLocation for once

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But since I'm currently using ALL providers and not getting more than a maximum of one updates I don't see how selecting "the best provider" would change that. And I only used getLastKnownLocation for debugging purposes.